# Borrar tabla SQLite con botón

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

**Buenas, tengo un inconveniente a la hora de eliminar una tabla `SQLite` desde un botón. Me sale el siguiente **error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

El inconveniente con esto, es que no es nula ya que para poder efectuar el método, corroboro que haya datos en la tabla de la siguiente manera. Primero, creo un método para cargar un `Array`:

```
public ArrayList llenarMensajes() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.leer();
        String[] campos = new String[]{GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_ID, GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TEXTO, GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TRUE_FALSE};
        Cursor c = db.query(GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS, campos, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                mensajes.setIdMensaje(c.getInt(0));
                mensajes.setText(c.getString(1));
                mensajes.setBooleano(c.getInt(2));
                list.add(mensajes);
            }
        } finally { c.close(); }
        this.cerrarDB();
        return list;
    }
```

Luego, desde la activity pregunto si ese `Array` está vacío así:

```
if(new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).llenarMensajes().isEmpty()){
                        Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                        mensajes.setText("¡Hey, responde! ¡Despierta!");
                        mensajes.setBooleano(0);
                        new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).guardar(mensajes);

                        Intent jugar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParteUnoCapUno.class);
                        startActivity(jugar);
                    }else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder crearNuevo = new AlertDialog.Builder(CapituloUno.this)
                                .setTitle("¡Atención!")
                                .setMessage("Iniciar una nueva partida hará que se borren sus datos guardados, ¿Desea continuar?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).borrarTabla();

                                        Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                                        mensajes.setText("¡Hey, responde! ¡Despierta!");
                                        mensajes.setBooleano(0);
                                        new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).guardar(mensajes);

                                        Intent jugar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParteUnoCapUno.class);
                                        startActivity(jugar);
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                                });
                        AlertDialog mostrar = crearNuevo.create();
                        mostrar.show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Lo cual funciona, ya que si hay datos me sale el `AlertDialog`. El inconveniente se genera en esta línea:

```
new GuardadoBD(getApplicationContext()).borrarTabla();
```

Este es el método que utilizo para borrar la tabla:

```
public void borrarTabla(){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS);
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

**Actualización**

Clase **GuardadoBD:**

```
public class GuardadoBD implements Serializable {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public GuardadoBD(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }
    private void leer() {
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    private void escribir() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    private void cerrarDB() {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
    private ContentValues mapaMensajes(Mensajes mensajes) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TEXTO, mensajes.getText());
        cv.put(GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TRUE_FALSE, mensajes.getBooleano());
        return cv;
    }
    public long guardar(Mensajes mensajes) {
        this.escribir();
        long rowID = db.insert(GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS, null, mapaMensajes(mensajes));
        this.cerrarDB();
        return rowID;
    }
    public ArrayList llenarMensajes() {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.leer();
        String[] campos = new String[]{GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_ID, GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TEXTO, GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TRUE_FALSE};
        Cursor c = db.query(GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS, campos, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                mensajes.setIdMensaje(c.getInt(0));
                mensajes.setText(c.getString(1));
                mensajes.setBooleano(c.getInt(2));
                list.add(mensajes);
            }
        } finally { c.close(); }
        this.cerrarDB();
        return list;
    }
    public ArrayList llenarMensajesPorID(int idMensaje) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
        this.leer();
        String[] campos = new String[]{GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_ID, GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_TEXTO};
        String where = GuardadoTabla.MENSAJE_ID + " = " + idMensaje + ";";
        Cursor c = db.query(GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS, campos, where, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Mensajes mensajes = new Mensajes();
                mensajes.setIdMensaje(c.getInt(0));
                mensajes.setText(c.getString(1));
                list.add(mensajes);
            }
        } finally { c.close(); }
        this.cerrarDB();
        return list;
    }

    public void borrarTabla(){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS);
    }

    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, GuardadoTabla.DB_NAME, null, GuardadoTabla.DB_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////Respuestas programadas
            db.execSQL(GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJE_SQL);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////Respuestas usuario
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }
    }
}
```

Clase **GuardadoTabla:**

```
public class GuardadoTabla {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "dbnowthegame00001.db";//nombre de la bd
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;//version


    //TABLA MENSAJE
    public static final String TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS= "tablaMensajesGuardados";

    //Columnas
    public static final String MENSAJE_ID = "idMensaje";
    public static final String MENSAJE_TEXTO = "textoMensaje";
    public static final String MENSAJE_TRUE_FALSE = "textoTrueFalse";

    //string del create
    public static final String TABLA_MENSAJE_SQL =
            "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS + "(" +
                    MENSAJE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    MENSAJE_TEXTO + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                    MENSAJE_TRUE_FALSE + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0);" ;
}
```

Comment: Agrega toda la clase GuardadoBD

Comment: A mi también me pasa que no ubico en el código, donde esta la clase  "GuardadoTabla"    ni que guarda la constante  "TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS"

Comment: Listo @Elenasys

Comment: Ya lo he añadido @iqanansoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso como comentas el problema se presenta aqui:

```
public void borrarTabla(){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS);
}
```

y es provocado porque la instancia de la base de datos no esta inicializada, deberías validar e inicializar en caso de que la instancia tenga valor null, modifica tu método de esta forma:

```
public void borrarTabla(Context context){
   if(dbHelper == null){   
      dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
   }
   if(db == null){
      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + GuardadoTabla.TABLA_MENSAJES_GUARDADOS);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido :D

Comment: Excelente Franqo, saludos!